# Combined output on multiple logstash according to document ID

Tags: json, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a json log from RabbitMq. In my case, I consume three different ques using three different logstash service and it will output to elasticsearch using the same index. Let assume we have log A, log B and log C. The structure of these log like these :

[Example of Log A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwqmu.png)

[Example of Log B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POB8E.png)

[Example of Log C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mRwu.png)

The config file to consume  and send these log to elastic same as:

[Logstash.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPSSi.png)

**Question => How to combined these three different log base on document_id before send to elastic with the same index ?**

Perhaps the JSON ouput will looks like these :

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAlZ6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use document_id to combine the logs on elastic search side and you can use elastic search update query to perform an update function so that it will merge with the existing record.

The following code will check if there is a document on elastic search with the document id and if there is no document, it will create a new document.
If there is a document with the document id it will perform a update query.

For clarification look into 
[docs-update-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

Try this following code:

```
elasticsearch {

                hosts => [ "xxxxxx"]
                index => "combined"

                action => "update"

                doc_as_upsert => true

                document_id => "%{[header][serialNum]}"

}
```

Comment: Hi Thivya ! Thank you for replying me...your answer really help for me. All logs combined on one index goodjob! Unfortunately it replace all log with the same field and attributes. I wonder how to combined it with the same index and ID into an oject or array. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I see an answer that suggests to use update option,

Using elasticsearch "action => update" will degrade your performance like crazy. As the traffic increases you will see ES cluster working very hard.

"update" will first cause ES to search the document, merge the document, delete the existing document and add this new merged document.

Thats a lot of processing!

My answer:

Use aggregate filter. There is a task_id field to sort it. You can set this to

```
aggregate {
 task_id => %{[header][serialNum]}
 ...
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html